# un-mounting a davfs2 fails without any error (no open files)

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, nextcloud, davfs2

How can I dismount or debug why this mount can't be unmounted?
background:

- Kubuntu 20.04
- lsof $mountpoint => empty list
- all terminal windows are closed
- all other apps are closed.
- a webdav davfs $url is mounted on $mountpoint via:
  `sudo mount -t davfs https://server/path $mp`

When I try to unmount, nothing happens, and no errors are displayed:

```
~$ sudo umount $mountpoint
~$
```

But $mountpoint is still mounted, No errors were given.

How can I unnmount it without a full restart?

How can I debug this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here. I was not able to unmount the webdav folder with `umount`. No error reported, but the resource was not unmounted.

Reporting all mounts shows the webdav resource as  `fuse` type and not `davfs`, as I was expecting. That triggered the solution.

```
mount
```

```
(...)
https://server/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/geonext/ on /home/qgis/nextcloud type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=1002,group_id=1002,allow_other,max_read=16384,uid=1002,gid=1002,user=qgis,helper=davfs)
```

#### Solution

```
fusermount -u /home/qgis/nextcloud
```

The resource was unmounted.

Comment: In my case I had to add sudo to the beginning as it was mounted by root: `sudo fusermount -u /home/qgis/nextcloud`